# In there a way to save a constantly changing value once a day and store it in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently using a google sheet to manage my portfolio. I want to save the value of my portfolio every day and save those numbers to create a growth graph. I want to take the value from one cell, paste it to another and the next day grab the value again from the same cell and paste on the cell under the one of the previous day without loosing my previous value. I am trying to create an AppScript script but I cant figure out how to go to the next cell once the day changes.

```
function Paste() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")

  var cellNumber = 3;
  var cell = "C" + cellNumber;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(cell).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

};
```

I want to increase cellNumber once a day!

Comment: Show relevant code snippet. See [mcve]

Comment: get the `sheet`  and use `cellnumber = sheet.getLastRow()+1`

Comment: Try using `sheet.appendRow()`

Comment: Have you consider using a time based installable trigger as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)? Also just to make sure before I post an answer, you basically want to get this value from this cell and paste it in one sheet every day (in the next row or column storing past values), **am I right**?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Paste() {
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var srcss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('sssid');//source of information spreadsheet
  var desss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('dssid');//storage destination spreadsheet
  var srcsh=srcss.getSheetByName('source sheet name');
  var dessh=desss.getSheetByName('destination sheet name');
  var value=srcsh.getRange('C3').getValue();
  dessh.appendRow([ts,value]);
};
```